# Checking values extracted from Collection against primitive value in AssertJ

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assertj

I had this case where I needed that all the objects in a collection have a specific boolean value in a field. extracting() seemed like a very good candidate for this. I was able to 'access' the field pretty easily but when I wanted to check it againt the value I was not able to find a clean way to do it in the API. The first thing I came up was the following:

```
        SomeService someService = new SomeService();
        List<ClassA> llList = someService.getList();
        assertThat(llList).extracting("someBoolean")
                .are(new Condition<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean matches(Object o) {
                        return Boolean.FALSE.equals(o);
                    }
                });
```

This seems like it is such common thing to check that I am buffled that I could not find something better in the AssertJ API. To enhance readability I next did the the following:

```
assertThat(llList).extracting("someBoolean")
                .are(createBooleanCondition(false));

public static Condition<Object> createBooleanCondition(boolean expected){
       return new Condition<Object>() {
           @Override
           public boolean matches(Object o) {
               return new Boolean(expected).equals(o);
           }
       };
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to express this kind of assertion with the AssertJ?

NOTE: I could use a java8 lambda to make this cleaner but my question is geared towards assertj and I also have the hard rule that I need this to compile in java 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check that every extracted boolean values are false, I would simply do:

```
assertThat(llList).extracting("someBoolean").containsOnly(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

A quite simple way for that is...

```
assertThat( llList ).filteredOn( "someBoolean", Boolean.FALSE ).isEmpty();
```

Of course, this will require reflection on AssertJ's side, but that's the price to pay for something like that...

Comment: If I am reading this correctly if I need everything to be false the I need to pass Boolean.TRUE on filteredOn(...).  Right?

Comment: My bad, yes. It's simply `filteredOn( fieldName, expectedValue )`. See the api doc (Version 2.x, for java < 8) here: http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#filteredOn%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29